Worksheet GetLock() and Async method
In try block I used getlock method, then call an async method, for calling async method throw an exception in finally block.
try{
workbook.WorkbookSet.GetLock();
// call async method
}
finally{
workbook.WorkbookSet.ReleaseLock();
}

Exception :
ReleaseLock() called without matching preceding GetLock().

what should I do If I want to use both GetLock and async method ?

What are you trying to do? Why use Excel interop at all? It really, really matters, especially in web applications. Excel interop actually uses COM calls, which are thread-specific. In desktop apps await returns execution to the calling thread, in web apps it doesn't. It's infinitely easier to use a library like EPPlus, Sylvan.Excel, ClosedXML etc to create Excel files than install Excel on the server and try to avoid flooding it with orphaned Excel instances. And buying an Excel license for every single user, including anonymous ones. Excel has no per-server license

what should I do don't use Excel Interop, explain the actual problem so people can help you solve it. If you want to generate a report from query results or objects, almost all libraries can fill a sheet with sheet.LoadFromCollection, LoadFromDataReader or something similar

GetLock and ReleaseLock expect to run on the same thread. If there is no SynchronizationContext when your code runs, then the finally block will likely run on a different thread, hence ReleaseLock will fail.

So you'd need to await asynchronous operation and also use ConfigureAwait(false)

Actually I want to read excel to retrieve the worksheet name and worksheet headers of each sheet, I didn't write anything @PanagiotisKanavos

You don't need locks for this. All libraries can read sheet names and cell contents but some libraries are specialized at reading. For example ExcelDataReader can read an Excel file and return an IDataReader that can be used to import data into a database. You can use the Name property to check each sheet's name. Sylvan.Data.Excel works in a similar way. In both cases you can get the column names and types with GetSchema

@mestu what do you want the sheet and column names for? If you want to import the data into a SQL Server database you can pass the IDataReader created by ExcelDataReader or Sylvan directly to SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer. if you want to display the data, you could load it into a DataTable display that on a grid
